# Comparing large boolean expressions for equivalence

Tags: python

I am trying to simplify and compare very large boolean expressions for equivalence. I've traditionally used `simplify_logic` from `sympy` to simplify an expression and then compare the two strings for equivalence. This only works well if the expressions contain 8 or less elements. If I am trying to compare two expressions that have 15+ elements each it just hangs (because the time it takes increases exponentially). Are there any Python packages or other roundabout ways to try and accomplish this?

**Update with random example**

Exp1 = 'A|B&(C|D|E)&F|H|I|J|(K&L&M)|K'

Exp2 = 'A&B&C&(D|E|F|J|K|L)&M&K&O&P'

`Exp1 == Exp2 ----> False`

These are obviously not the same, but an example of some runaway expressions that I might encounter. For sanitys sake each element is only 1 letter long when  my ACTUAL case each expression is a mix of 10 numbers/letters each.

Comment: Can you show us a sample or two of what you're trying to compare?

Comment: Please edit your question to include samples of your working input (the 8 or less elements), non-working input (the 15+ elements), along with how you are comparing them now. The more you help us, the more likely we are to help you

Comment: So you have two strings, such as `"x and y"` and `"not x or not y"` and you want to analyze them to see if they will produce the same result?

Comment: How many variables do the two expressions have?

Comment: Unless I'm missing something here, wouldn't the only truly reliable approach be to actually evaluate both expressions and then compare the actual results?

Comment: @antred You can do algebraic simplification without evaluating them, using identities like `not (x and y)` = `not x or not y`.

Comment: I will type out an example. The assumption is that each expression could have up to 100 variables and will always have more than 8 (where sympy slows waaay down)

Comment: @antred The OP doesn't mean a Python expression, i.e. something that evaluates to a value. I'm assuming, since they mention SymPy. They mean abstract, mathematical / logical expressions. So, take for example, we know that the boolean expression "not (A or B)" is *equivalent* to "not A and not B" (De Morgan's law). Presumably the OP is talking about very complex expressions. Brute force, you could generate truth tables for both expressions and check if they match, but that scales in polynomial time, I'm guessing.

Comment: Brute-force using truth tables takes O(m * 2^n) time, where the expression length is m and the number of variables is n.

Comment: @kaya3 Thanks for the insight. So yea, it scales in exponential time. Yuck.

Answer (score 4):

Testing equivalence of Boolean expressions is as computationally complex as solving the [Boolean satisfiability problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem).

To reduce in one direction, a formula is satisfiable if and only if it is not equivalent to the formula `False`. In the other direction, two formulae `A` and `B` are equivalent if and only if `(A and not B) or (not A and B)` is not satisfiable.

This problem is NP-complete, so there is no known solution that works efficiently for large formulae in the worst case. However, "large" is relative; [says Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem#Algorithms_for_solving_SAT):

> Since the SAT problem is NP-complete, only algorithms with exponential worst-case complexity are known for it. In spite of this, efficient and scalable algorithms for SAT were developed during the 2000s and have contributed to dramatic advances in our ability to automatically solve problem instances involving tens of thousands of variables and millions of constraints (i.e. clauses).

So your problem, with only dozens of clauses and hundreds of variables, should be quite feasible. Wikipedia suggests some algorithms:

> There are two classes of high-performance algorithms for solving instances of SAT in practice: the [conflict-driven clause learning](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conflict-driven_clause_learning) algorithm, which can be viewed as a modern variant of the [DPLL algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DPLL_algorithm) (well known implementations include Chaff and GRASP) and stochastic local search algorithms, such as [WalkSAT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WalkSAT).

Comment: Thanks for the info. I had assumed what I am trying to accomplish probably isn't possible but had to ask since I couldn't come to a definite conclusion.

Comment: It should be quite feasible for problems of your size; see my edit.